# Get array from Firestore Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fairly new to programming so apologies if I sound like a total noob.

The following is my FIRE STORE Database

[Firestore Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwCkE.png)

I need to import this into Kotlin. I used the following code to retrieve data from maps.

```
val PropRef = db.collection("properties").document("JSZyZ2KuIH5xRZ01t1zA")
    PropRef
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            var queueStatus = ArrayList<String>()
            for (document in result) {
                var checkintime= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView17)
                var docMap1 = document.get("checkInTime") as Map<String, *>
                queueStatus.add(docMap1["start"] as String)
                queueStatus.add(docMap1["end"] as String)
                checkintime.text= queueStatus[1].toString()
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to get data from arrays and store them into variables. Your help is immensely appreciated. Thanks in advance to the kind soul who helps me out on this